# CallKit report about end

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I need to notify CallKit when a call has ended. I do it through this function

```
let endCallAction = CXEndCallAction.init(call: uuid_var.uuid_test)
let transaction = CXTransaction.init()
transaction.addAction(endCallAction)
self.controller.request(transaction, completion: {error in print(error)})
self.provider.reportCall(with: uuid_var.uuid_test, endedAt: Date(), reason: .remoteEnded)
```

But I'm getting this error
`Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=4 "(null)")`

UUID is correct, end function in a same queue

Report about call looks like this:

```
self.provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid_var.uuid_test, update: update){ error in
                completion()
            }
```

Collecting UUID:
`uuid_var.uuid_test = UUID()`

I've checked, uuid same in all functions

Comment: Error 4 is an unknown call uuid.  Where/when do you set `uuid_var.uuid_test = UUID()` ? If this code runs again you will get a new, random, uuid.

Comment: I set it here
``` 
struct uuid_var {
        static var uuid_test:UUID = UUID()
    }
```
I check it in different functions, it's same

Comment: That doesn't tell me *where* you set it. ie. Where do you create the instance of that struct? As it `uuid_var` is a `struct` it is a value type.  You definitely run the risk of that structure being recreated if you ever assign it and mutate it.  You should store the call uuid in a `class`  instance - a reference type. The error code from CallKit says that the UUID of the call you are trying to end is unknown, so it is likely that you have created a new uuid at some point.